# linux alias to simplify a command line

Tags: linux, bash

I am new to writing Linux scripts (in fact I'm not sure if the proper term is Linux script or baSH script).  I do understand `source`-ing and the `alias` feature such as this:

```
alias l='ls -ltra'
```

What I want to accomplish is type the following shortcut statement

```
php ~/path/to/longProgram.php Argument1 -x -y -z --long-switch long-switch-value
```

as this:

```
lp Argument1 -x -y -z --long-switch long-switch-value
```

i.e. where I can call `lp` from any where, and where all of the arguments as-given get passed to `longProgram.php`.  How would I do this as an alias?

Comment: Circa 1996: "For almost every purpose, aliases are superseded by shell functions."  Don't use aliases.  Write a function.

Comment: "bash script" is proper; Linux is an operating system on which you can run a number of shells (`bash`, `dash`, `ash`, `zsh`, `sh`, `ksh`, etc), each of whose syntax and feature set is not 100% identical to any other shell's.

Answer (score 4):

To make an invocation of `lp Argument1 -x -y -z --long-switch long-switch-value` result in a call to `php ~/path/to/longProgram.php Argument1 -x -y -z --long-switch long-switch-value`, you have a few options.  The simplest is to put this in your ~/.bashrc:

```
lp() { php "$HOME/path/to/longProgram.php" "$@"; }
```

Answer (score 1):

```
alias lp='php ~/path/to/longProgram.php'
```

would normally work, even if it is not a good practice. An alias is simply a find and replace feature so I see no reason of this not working. However you need to be the exact user whose home contain the program.

PS: Also verify that `lp` is not already assigned to another command.

Answer (score 0):

I just found a way to set an alias command and save it for next time.

```
nano ~/.bashrc or ~/.bash_aliases
```

add your aliases in this file

Ex:

```
alias lp='php ~/path/to/longProgram.php
```

ctrl+x to save the file, then

```
source ~/.bashrc or ~/.bash_aliases
```

You will be able to use the alias command everytime you login as the target user.

Note:

> If you want to use ~/.bash_aliases, be sure that the ~/.bashrc file has following commands.

```
if [ -f ~/.bash_aliases ]; then
    . ~/.bash_aliases
fi
```

I prefer using bash_aliases to keep your custom alias clean and management in a centrilized file.

Referece:
https://www.cyberciti.biz/faq/create-permanent-bash-alias-linux-unix/